# How to script an already deployed SSIS project from SSISDB - SqlServer 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I want to know if, for an already deployed SSIS project, from SSISDB-Sql Server 2012, I can script the hole package, with all its parameters, connection managers, references, everything?
   I have an already deployed SSIS project but I must deploy it using scripts to some other database and I would like to script all project parameters.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export whole SSIS project from SSISDB as an .ispac file from SQL Server Management Studio; just select project and *Export...* from context menu. However, this file will contain only project with its parameters, connection managers and packages; you can deploy it on another server without references and environments.

You cannot export referencies and environments from SSISDB with SSMS. There is [an excellent article with script](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ru/2014/02/deploying-ssis-2012-environments.html) sample. Script generates a set of t-sql commands recreating environment and its references with project.

Combining these two approaches you will be done.