# How can we synchronize SSIS and jobs across 2 servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have a DRP and need to 'back-up' our ssis and jobs from the production server to the DRP server.
How can an ssis in SQL integration services be copied to the second server when the ssis in production is added/modified ?

Same thing for jobs.

We already us log shipping to synch our data and structure.

We are running SQL 2012 and we store the ssis in the package store.

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server are you dealing with? And, how are you storing the SSIS packages in production? File system, MSDB, SSISDB?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a **Prod to DRP** copy procedure. You can  [export *SSIS Projects and packages* and script *SSISDB Environments*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566653/1010622) and [SQL Agent *Job definitions*](https://serverfault.com/a/685183). After that, deploy SSIS Packages and restore SSIS Environments and Jobs from generated scripts. This can be packaged in a PowerShell script to automate it.